# import github packages while building packages

Tags: r, github, package

How can I import github packages while building packages in namespace and description file of the package. Note that I want to submit built package on cran repository.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but if the package is already installed, you can simply add the tag `@import` to the roxygen comment of the function that requires it. Then run `devtools::document()` to update namespace.

Comment: Alternatively, this [vignette](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/vignettes/dependencies.Rmd) explains how to add packages in non standard repository by manipulating the DESCRIPTION file:.

Comment: @thepule I did what you said in the first comment but I got this error: "Error: Line starting 'igraph ( >= 1.0.1 ), ...' is malformed!
"

Comment: @thepule I just type "devtools::document()" in the console

Comment: @thepule if I want to submit the package on cran, must not it  have some dependencies on other repositories such as github?